# Does the locationManager:didEnterRegion works when stopUpdatingLocation is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I am wondering does the `CLLocationManager` delegates like `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` work when `stopUpdatingLocation` is called or the the method `startUpdatingLocation` must called all the time to make them called ?

Another thing is where the best place to start regions monitoring

Comment: bro have you got your answer ??

Answer (score 0):

If your app enters the background you are expected to call `stopUpdatingLocation` to preserve energy. If you use `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:` your delegate methods `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` will be called accordingly, even if your app is in background/suspended. Another option is to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. Then your app will be woken up from suspended or terminated status.